# In Magento 2 will new sales overwrite migrated sales orders?

Tags: magento2, database, sales-order, data-migration

I'm currently migrating an existing **Magento 1 site to Magento 2** and I wondered how the sales number would behave after migrating data.

We’ve migrated all of our existing sales data from our Magento 1 system but I wondered how this worked with the new orders on the Magento 2 system.

The Migration tool (Ubertheme) seems to have kept the original ID numbers for our sales orders (which I’m happy about as it makes them easier to search) but as the new orders seem to reset the counter. I wondered how this would work when the numbering **“caught up”** with the migrated orders.

I realize that this is something that, most likely, has already been considered but I just wanted to make sure that the new orders will not conflict with/overwrite the original sales orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ubertheme, this will not be an issue, the orders will not overwrite.